# Multi buttons to change value for UItextfield

Tags: ios, uitextfield

What would be the best practice to achieve the following without having to have multiple `IBActions`?

[image]

When one of the blue buttons are clicked i want it to change the input field below to the VALUE assigned by the button.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set UIButton tag for Button1, Button2... As 0, 1, and so on

[image]

**EDIT**

```
    -(IBAction)buttonAction:(UIButton *)sender
     {
         switch(sender) {
        case 0: 
             //Change UITextValue
        break;

        case 1: 
             //Change UITextValue
        break;

        default: //Not found
        break;

      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Shekar, ill take a look quick.

Comment: @SnakeBlisken As you have more than 2 buttons.Its better to use switch case instead of if-else.Because it will take less memory cycles.

Comment: Yes, will do! Thanks Gents!

Answer (score 0):

U can also achieve this by setting the target to same selector 
for example

```
 UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 UIButton *button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 [button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



button1.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 100);
button2.frame = CGRectMake(20, 130, 100, 100);
button1.tag = 100;



button1.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
button2.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
button2.tag = 200;

[self.view addSubview:button1];
[self.view addSubview:button2];

//for selector

 -(void)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender
 {

   NSLog(@"same target and tag =%d",sender.tag);


}
```